# How do I hash key and secret message in crc32 using Python hashlib or zlib?

Tags: python-3.x, zlib, crc32, hashlib

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

key = b'sdfgfcxc'
secret = b'?45$dfd*632sd!'
base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key, secret, hashlib.sha512).digest())
```

I want to hash the same key and secret fields using crc32 algorithm. But, hashlib doesn't provide crc32 hashing. I believe we can use zlib to apply crc32 hash, but how do I combine both key and secret for getting a crc32 hash using zlib? Or does hashlib itself provides some option?

Comment: What exactly would you like to hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply concatenate `key` and `secret` and use `zlib.crc32()` to compute the CRC-32 of that sequence of bytes.

However, are you sure that's what you want? There's a reason that `hashlib` does not have a CRC-32, which is that it is easy to spoof. I.e., come up with different data that has the same hash.

Comment: yes, i do need crc32 as an option. The final application will have user selection option to select the hashing type. The default one is sha256 from hashlib. Thankyou, for the clarification. Really appreciate it.